# Adding a moving vline in a Shiny Application (based on user input)

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following shiny application:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

UI <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = ""),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    mainPanel(
        actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
        plotOutput("plot_timeseries")
    )
  )
)

Server <- function(input, output) {


  output$plot_timeseries <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()+
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,35)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept =  1)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

As you'll see I have a vline now at x = 1. However what I would like to achieve it that when I press the "go" button a counter should be initiated (adding 1 with every second). So 5 seconds after pressing the go button the variable should 6 and the vline value should be 6.

Any thoughts on how I can get this working in the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, which uses two `reactiveVal`'s; one to keep track of whether the counter should increment, and one with the current value of the counter.

Hope this helps!

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

UI <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = ""),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    mainPanel(
      actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
      plotOutput("plot_timeseries")
    )
  )
)

Server <- function(input, output, session) {

  counter <- reactiveVal(1)
  action <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

  # When goButton is clicked, set action() from FALSE to TRUE or the other way around.
  observeEvent(input$goButton,
               {
                 action(!action())
               })

  # Add an oberserver that invalidates every second, and increments the counter if action()==TRUE
  observe({ invalidateLater(1000, session)
    isolate({
      if(action())
      {
        # Add 1 to our counter
        counter(counter() + 1) 
      }
    })
  })

  output$plot_timeseries <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()+
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,35)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept =  counter())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```